# Create Hourly Average query from Logger table

Tags: sql, pivot-table, average

I use a logger table with timestamp,point id and value fields.
The control system adds a record each time a point id value is changed to the logger table.

Here's an example of the SELECT query of the logger table:

[image: Logger Table results exmple]

I want to run query on that table and get in return 1 hourly average values of some tags(point id's of different value - for example: 1 hourly average of point_id=LT_174, 1 hourly average of point_id=AT_INK and so on).
I would like to present the results list in pivot table results list.
Can I do that? and if it's imposible to get all requested tags together, how can I run the same query for 1 tag? (I use VB.Net as a platform for running this query, so I can build it by calculating all requested tags in a loop, each time 1 tag).
I'll be happy to get ideas and suggestions for this problem.

Comment: could you please provider your sample output

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution:

Comment: SELECT
    DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,[time])/2*2,0) [timestamp],
    AVG(value) [AVG_VALUE]
FROM
    VfiTagNumHistory
WHERE ([time] BETWEEN '2018-01-06 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-06 12:00:00') and gateid=58983394
GROUP BY
 DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,[time])/2*2,0)
ORDER BY
    DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,[time])/2*2,0)

Comment: The example above calculate 2 hours average values of tag with id number 58983394 between 2018-01-06 and 2018-12-06.